# Send multiple messages with IMessageHandlerContext

Tags: c#, task

I have a MessageHandler and I need to send 2 messages to the same handler at different interval. My code will send to the BUS only the second message. The expected result would be that the first message to be sent after 1 minute and the second message to be sent after 3 minutes(2+1).

```
public async Task Handle(EmailMessage message, IMessageHandlerContext context)
    {
        switch (message.Action)
        {
            case Constants.Ticket.TicketConstants.Action.SendBothMails:
                DeferNextMessage(message, context);
                break;

            case Constants.Ticket.TicketConstants.Action.SendFirstMail:
                //logic for the first email
                var a = "firstMail";
                break;
            case   Constants.Ticket.TicketConstants.Action.SendSecondMail:
                //logic for the second email
                var b = "secondMail";
                break;
        }
    }

private async void DeferNextMessage(EmailMessage currentMessage, IMessageHandlerContext context)
    {
        await Test1(currentMessage, context).ContinueWith(async t => {
            await Test2(currentMessage, context);
            }); 
    }

 private async Task Test1(EmailMessage currentMessage,  IMessageHandlerContext context)
    {
        var sendFirstMailOptions = new SendOptions();

        sendFirstMailOptions.DelayDeliveryWith(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
        sendFirstMailOptions.RouteToThisEndpoint();

        await context.Send(currentMessage.SpawnFirstEmailMessage(), sendFirstMailOptions).ConfigureAwait(false);

    }

    private async Task Test2(EmailMessage currentMessage, IMessageHandlerContext context)
    {
        var sendSecondMailOptions = new SendOptions();

        sendSecondMailOptions.DelayDeliveryWith(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
        sendSecondMailOptions.RouteToThisEndpoint();

        await context.Send(currentMessage.SpawnSecondEmailMessage(), sendSecondMailOptions).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```